# Why isn't my node aligning to page text area correctly?

Tags: tikz-node

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,pagesize=auto,hidelinks,cleardoublepage=empty,parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=8in,margin=2cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm,showframe=false]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\gdef\chapterlabel{} \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
    {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\%}}{0pt}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
            \node(main)[yshift=-7cm] at (current page.north west)
            {%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,7cm);
                    \node[anchor=east,yshift=-3cm] at (current page text area.north east) {\color{white}\large Chapter \thechapter};%
                    \node[anchor=east,yshift=-4cm] at (current page text area.north east) {\color{white} #1};%
                \end{tikzpicture}
            };%
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}[0pt]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

It renders as:

[image]

Notice how the right edge of the chapter title does not align with the right edge of the body text. Why is this? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You should **not** use `titlesec` and a KOMA class together

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not sure what that means, or how to fix it. Or why everything else seems to work despite the fact that I'm apparently doing something wrong.

Comment: There is a a clear warning that KOMA classes and `titlesec` are not compatible to each other.

Answer (score 2):

A `node` has an `inner sep`, a given distance from the node content to the border of the node. By default this is 0.333em, you should set `inner sep=0` for your two nodes.

In addition to Christian's comments about `titlesec` and KOMA, you should also take [Zarko's advice in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417910), and not nest `tikzpicture`s. It can sometimes cause problems, and it is not at all needed here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, pagesize=auto, hidelinks, cleardoublepage=empty, parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in, paperwidth=8in, margin=2cm, heightrounded, bindingoffset=5mm, showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\gdef\chapterlabel{} \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
    {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\%}}{0pt}
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
            \node(main)[yshift=-7cm] at (current page.north west)
            {%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                    \draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,7cm);
                    \node[anchor=east,yshift=-3cm,inner sep=0] at (current page text area.north east) {\color{white}\large Chapter \thechapter};%
                    \node[anchor=east,yshift=-4cm,inner sep=0] at (current page text area.north east) {\color{white} #1};%
                \end{tikzpicture}
            };%
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}[0pt]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn, that was indeed the problem. What frustrates me is that I _knew_ about `inner sep` as I've used it elsewhere. I just didn't notice the connection in this particular context. I'm really struggling when it comes to debugging LaTeX. How would I have known this? Is there some tooling I'm missing that allows you to see where values are being derived from? Why spacing is being added/not added etc?

Comment: @KentBoogaart In a case like this I suppose the first thing you could have done is to draw the border of the nodes (add `draw=white`), that would make it clearer how the node is positioned.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the usage of package `titlesec` with a **KOMA-Script class** is not recommended. So here is a suggestion without `titlesec` and `tikz` that also works for unnumbered chapters like table of contents and for chapter titles longer than text width:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,cleardoublepage=empty,parskip,chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=8in,
            margin=2cm,heightrounded,
            bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\Huge\scshape\color{white},
  prefixfont=\large,
  beforeskip=-1sp,
  afterskip=1sp
]{chapter}

\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \parbox[b][5cm]{\textwidth}{%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{\textcolor{black}{\rule{2\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}%
      \raggedchapter
      \raisebox{.5\baselineskip}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\raggedchapter#2#3}}}%
      \par
  }{%
    #2#3% original definition for other levels
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Chapter with long, long, long title that needs more than one line}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that you have to use a different font like `libertine` to get chapter titles using `\sffamily\bfseries\scshape`.

Answer (score 1):

beside what [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) was indicated, you should not nested `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,pagesize=auto,
               hidelinks,cleardoublepage=empty,
                parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,
            paperwidth=8in,margin=2cm,heightrounded,
            bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\gdef\chapterlabel{} \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
    {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\%}}{0pt}
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
    every node/.append style={text=white, inner xsep=0pt}]
        \draw[fill=black] (current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth,-3cm);
        \node[left, yshift=-3cm, font=\large] at (current page text area.north east) {Chapter \thechapter};%
        \node[left,yshift=-4cm] at (current page text area.north east) {#1};%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{3cm}[0pt]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

the above code is also little bit corrected regarding use of font size and text color.

[image]

Comment: Ah, didn't even notice that.